# How to block bootstrap in stata with set of dummy variables as controls

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, bootstrap, stata, clustered-standard-errors

I want to estimate a Multiple multivariate regression of the type
$$y_1=a_1+b_1*x+c_1*\text{countrydummies}+e_1 \\
y_2=a_2+b_2*x+c_2*\text{countrydummies}+e_2 \\
... \\
y_N=a_N+b_N*x+c_N*\text{countrydummies}+e_N, $$
where $\text{countrydummies}$ is a set of dummy variables, which are nuisance variables (I don't need their coefficients but I need to control for them to get the right estimates for the $b$'s). I am interested in running a joint test $b_1=b_2=...=b_N=0$, hence I cannot just separately estimate these equations, say by OLS.

The data is on individual level, with some individuals appearing multiple times. Hence, an additional complication is that I need to cluster standard errors on individual level.

In stata, multiple multivariate regression is done with the command `mvreg`, which however does not allow for the option `vce(cluster individualid)` as OLS does. Hence, in order to cluster the standard errors, I am using cluster bootstrap which is allowed:

```
bootstrap, reps(10000) seed(1) cluster(individualid) : mvreg y1 y2 y3 = x countrdummy1 countrydummy2 countrydummy3
test x //test whether coefficient of x jointly equals 0 in all equations
```

But this does not work; the noisily option in bootstrap reveals the error: "collinearity in replicate sample is not the same as the full sample, posting missing values". In other words, in some bootstrap samples no individuals from country 1 are sampled, hence $\text{countrydummy1}=0$ for all observations in that sample, and the coefficient of that dummy cannot be estimated (though the coefficients of the $b$'s can always be estimated for every bootstrap sample). Stata then discards all estimates from that bootstrap sample, even the $b$-coefficients that I am interested in.

How can I still get my $b$-coefficients while controlling for the countrydummies and while clustering on the individual level? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions. One is to use factor variable notation and adjust the bootstrap options so that Stata knows exactly what the panel structure is.

The second is to use `suest` to combine estimation results from separate regression and test the cross-equation restriction that way, which tends to be faster. In the example below, the results are quite similar for both approaches in a dataset of 27K observations of log wages, hours, and weeks worked last year for 4,658 women in 12 industries (analogous to countries from your example).

Reproducible code is at the very bottom, and the detailed output looks like this:

```
. webuse nlswork, clear
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. 
. /* Create a data problem similar to yours: only one woman works in industry 2 */
. drop if ind_code == 2 & idcode !=492
(44 observations deleted)

. levelsof idcode if ind_code == 2, sep(,)
492

. 
. /* Get rid of data with missings to make bs and suest more comparable */
. foreach var of varlist ln_wage wks_work hours tenure ind_code {
  2.         drop if missing(`var')
  3. }
(0 observations deleted)
(703 observations deleted)
(61 observations deleted)
(420 observations deleted)
(306 observations deleted)

. 
. /* summary stats */
. sum idcode ln_wage wks_work hours tenure ind_code

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      idcode |     27,000    2592.656    1488.599          1       5159
     ln_wage |     27,000    1.681831    .4771389          0   5.263916
    wks_work |     27,000    54.29211    29.03071          0        104
       hours |     27,000    36.62556    9.806088          1        168
      tenure |     27,000    3.175111       3.773          0   25.91667
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
    ind_code |     27,000    7.716778    2.994094          1         12

. distinct idcode ind_code 

          |        Observations
          |      total   distinct
----------+----------------------
   idcode |      27000       4658
 ind_code |      27000         12

. 
. /* (1) Bootsrap Version */
. bootstrap, reps(1000) seed(1) cluster(idcode) idcluster(newid) group(idcode): mvreg ln_wage wks_work hours = c.tenure i.ind_code
(running mvreg on estimation sample)

Bootstrap replications (1000)
----+--- 1 ---+--- 2 ---+--- 3 ---+--- 4 ---+--- 5 
.xx.x...x.x.x.xx..x.x........x.x....x.xxx...xxx...    50
x....x.....x...x.xxx..x.......x..x.x..x....xx.xxx.   100
x.....x.xxx....xx..x.x...xxxx.x..xx....x..xxx...x.   150
....x...x...xx...xx.x.xx.x.x.x.x....x.x...x.x.....   200
.x.x.xx.xx....xx..x.x..xxxx..xx..x...xxx...xx.xxx.   250
..xx.x.....x..xx..x.x.x..xx..x....x..x....xxx....x   300
...x..x.x.x.xx..xx.xx.....xx.xxx..x........x.....x   350
.x.x.x.x..x........xxx...x........xx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx   400
x.x.........x.x..xxx.x.x......xxx..x.xxx...xx.x.xx   450
xxxxxx.x.x...x.xxx.x..x....x..x..x...x..x.....x.xx   500
xx.xx..x.....x................x.xx....xx...xx.xx..   550
..xx..x...........x...xxxx...x..x....x..xx.x.xx...   600
.xxxx....x.x...xxxx.......x..xx......x.x.......x..   650
.xx....xx..........xxx..x.xxx.x........x.xxx.xx...   700
.....x..xxx.x.x...xx.xx..xx..xxx..x.x...x.........   750
x.x..x.x.xx......x..x.x.xx..xx...xx.xx.x.xx..x....   800
.xx.x.x...xx.....x...x......x.xx.x.xx.x.xx.x....x.   850
xx....x..xxx.x...x...xx..x.x....x...xx.x...xxx..x.   900
.......x.x..x........x.x..x.........xxx.....x.....   950
.x.....x..xx...x..xx.x...........xx..x...xx.....x.  1000

Equation             Obs   Parms        RMSE    "R-sq"          F        P
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ln_wage           27,000      13    .4170391    0.2364     0.0000
wks_work          27,000      13    25.89568    0.2047     0.0000
hours             27,000      13    9.546167    0.0527     0.0000

                              (Replications based on 4,658 clusters in idcode)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ln_wage      |
      tenure |   .0387041   .0011947    32.40   0.000     .0363625    .0410457
             |
    ind_code |
          2  |   .4547731   .0605084     7.52   0.000     .3361789    .5733673
          3  |   .3981021   .0746456     5.33   0.000     .2517994    .5444048
          4  |   .2190064   .0614132     3.57   0.000     .0986388    .3393741
          5  |   .4966848   .0637349     7.79   0.000     .3717666     .621603
          6  |   .0574442   .0610242     0.94   0.347     -.062161    .1770494
          7  |   .3363647   .0628739     5.35   0.000     .2131341    .4595953
          8  |   .2862618   .0639139     4.48   0.000     .1609929    .4115308
          9  |  -.1561957   .0649936    -2.40   0.016    -.2835809   -.0288105
         10  |   .2520204   .0927237     2.72   0.007     .0702854    .4337555
         11  |   .3137684   .0612556     5.12   0.000     .1937096    .4338271
         12  |   .4094109   .0624453     6.56   0.000     .2870204    .5318014
             |
       _cons |   1.323099    .060375    21.91   0.000     1.204766    1.441432
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
wks_work     |
      tenure |   3.228072   .0572963    56.34   0.000     3.115773    3.340371
             |
    ind_code |
          2  |   9.149176   2.694226     3.40   0.001     3.868591    14.42976
          3  |   19.04214   3.366375     5.66   0.000     12.44417    25.64011
          4  |   8.639348   2.726275     3.17   0.002     3.295947    13.98275
          5  |   11.37263   2.833709     4.01   0.000     5.818658    16.92659
          6  |    7.26576   2.706783     2.68   0.007     1.960562    12.57096
          7  |   15.34795    2.77468     5.53   0.000     9.909682    20.78623
          8  |   12.66416   2.857067     4.43   0.000     7.064414    18.26391
          9  |   5.577913    2.81422     1.98   0.047     .0621422    11.09368
         10  |   8.179954   3.594833     2.28   0.023      1.13421     15.2257
         11  |   13.28184    2.73298     4.86   0.000     7.925295    18.63838
         12  |   14.92816   2.858224     5.22   0.000     9.326148    20.53018
             |
       _cons |   33.16003   2.693299    12.31   0.000     27.88126     38.4388
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
hours        |
      tenure |   .2684051   .0204307    13.14   0.000     .2283617    .3084486
             |
    ind_code |
          2  |   6.131882    1.32868     4.62   0.000     3.527717    8.736047
          3  |   .7585534    1.60399     0.47   0.636    -2.385209    3.902315
          4  |   3.818207   1.343197     2.84   0.004      1.18559    6.450825
          5  |   1.794674   1.405505     1.28   0.202    -.9600654    4.549413
          6  |  -.6213007   1.337806    -0.46   0.642    -3.243352    2.000751
          7  |    1.71609   1.337302     1.28   0.199    -.9049731    4.337153
          8  |  -.7934719   1.396452    -0.57   0.570    -3.530467    1.943523
          9  |  -2.809894   1.443578    -1.95   0.052    -5.639255    .0194659
         10  |  -3.832453    1.88034    -2.04   0.042    -7.517851   -.1470548
         11  |   .5212249   1.346317     0.39   0.699    -2.117508    3.159958
         12  |   2.572525   1.350724     1.90   0.057    -.0748452    5.219895
             |
       _cons |   34.73904   1.329201    26.14   0.000     32.13386    37.34423
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test tenure

 ( 1)  [ln_wage]tenure = 0
 ( 2)  [wks_work]tenure = 0
 ( 3)  [hours]tenure = 0

           chi2(  3) = 3647.85
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0000

. 
. /* (2) SUEST version */
. foreach var of varlist ln_wage wks_work hours {
  2.         quietly reg `var' c.tenure i.ind_code
  3.         estimates store `var'
  4. }

. 
. suest ln_wage wks_work hours, cluster(idcode)

Simultaneous results for ln_wage, wks_work, hours

                                                Number of obs     =     27,000

                               (Std. Err. adjusted for 4,658 clusters in idcode)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               |               Robust
               |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ln_wage_mean   |
        tenure |   .0387041   .0012007    32.24   0.000     .0363509    .0410574
               |
      ind_code |
            2  |   .4547731   .0614519     7.40   0.000     .3343296    .5752165
            3  |   .3981021   .0757321     5.26   0.000     .2496699    .5465342
            4  |   .2190064   .0622319     3.52   0.000     .0970341    .3409787
            5  |   .4966848   .0654283     7.59   0.000     .3684478    .6249218
            6  |   .0574442   .0622293     0.92   0.356    -.0645229    .1794113
            7  |   .3363647   .0634169     5.30   0.000     .2120699    .4606596
            8  |   .2862618   .0651725     4.39   0.000     .1585261    .4139976
            9  |  -.1561957   .0644334    -2.42   0.015    -.2824828   -.0299085
           10  |   .2520204    .093274     2.70   0.007     .0692068     .434834
           11  |   .3137684   .0622012     5.04   0.000     .1918562    .4356806
           12  |   .4094109   .0635462     6.44   0.000     .2848627    .5339592
               |
         _cons |   1.323099   .0613384    21.57   0.000     1.202878     1.44332
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ln_wage_lnvar  |
         _cons |   -1.74915   .0199195   -87.81   0.000    -1.788192   -1.710109
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
wks_work_mean  |
        tenure |   3.228072   .0579799    55.68   0.000     3.114434    3.341711
               |
      ind_code |
            2  |   9.149176   2.683027     3.41   0.001      3.89054    14.40781
            3  |   19.04214    3.31179     5.75   0.000     12.55115    25.53313
            4  |   8.639348   2.712702     3.18   0.001     3.322551    13.95615
            5  |   11.37263   2.841212     4.00   0.000     5.803952     16.9413
            6  |    7.26576   2.726532     2.66   0.008     1.921855    12.60966
            7  |   15.34795   2.766664     5.55   0.000     9.925392    20.77052
            8  |   12.66416   2.872687     4.41   0.000       7.0338    18.29453
            9  |   5.577913   2.795552     2.00   0.046     .0987321    11.05709
           10  |   8.179954   3.548792     2.30   0.021      1.22445    15.13546
           11  |   13.28184    2.71463     4.89   0.000     7.961261    18.60242
           12  |   14.92816   2.815027     5.30   0.000     9.410812    20.44552
               |
         _cons |   33.16003   2.685036    12.35   0.000     27.89746     38.4226
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
wks_work_lnvar |
         _cons |   6.508152   .0086775   750.00   0.000     6.491145     6.52516
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
hours_mean     |
        tenure |   .2684051   .0202729    13.24   0.000      .228671    .3081393
               |
      ind_code |
            2  |   6.131882   1.310478     4.68   0.000     3.563393    8.700371
            3  |   .7585534   1.676567     0.45   0.651    -2.527458    4.044565
            4  |   3.818207   1.315905     2.90   0.004     1.239082    6.397333
            5  |   1.794674   1.379751     1.30   0.193     -.909589    4.498937
            6  |  -.6213007   1.326101    -0.47   0.639    -3.220411    1.977809
            7  |    1.71609   1.327076     1.29   0.196    -.8849303     4.31711
            8  |  -.7934719   1.402872    -0.57   0.572    -3.543051    1.956108
            9  |  -2.809894   1.384053    -2.03   0.042    -5.522588   -.0972006
           10  |  -3.832453   1.905852    -2.01   0.044    -7.567855   -.0970512
           11  |   .5212249   1.323962     0.39   0.694    -2.073693    3.116143
           12  |   2.572525   1.335122     1.93   0.054    -.0442655    5.189315
               |
         _cons |   34.73904   1.312456    26.47   0.000     32.16668    37.31141
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
hours_lnvar    |
         _cons |   4.512279   .0222803   202.52   0.000     4.468611    4.555948
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test tenure

 ( 1)  [ln_wage_mean]tenure = 0
 ( 2)  [wks_work_mean]tenure = 0
 ( 3)  [hours_mean]tenure = 0

           chi2(  3) = 3520.19
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0000
```

---

**Code:**

```
webuse nlswork, clear

/* Create a data problem similar to yours: only one woman works in industry 2 */
drop if ind_code == 2 & idcode !=492
levelsof idcode if ind_code == 2, sep(,)

/* Get rid of data with missings to make bs and suest more comparable */
foreach var of varlist ln_wage wks_work hours tenure ind_code {
    drop if missing(`var')
}

/* summary stats */
sum idcode ln_wage wks_work hours tenure ind_code
distinct idcode ind_code 

/* (1) Bootsrap Version */
bootstrap, reps(1000) seed(1) cluster(idcode) idcluster(newid) group(idcode): mvreg ln_wage wks_work hours = c.tenure i.ind_code
test tenure

/* (2) SUEST version */
foreach var of varlist ln_wage wks_work hours {
    quietly reg `var' c.tenure i.ind_code
    estimates store `var'
}

suest ln_wage wks_work hours, cluster(idcode)
test tenure
```

---

**Addendum:**

Here's a second custom bootstrap that gets around the bad sample rejection issue. It "works" in the sense of using all the samples without rejecting the ones where the industry 2 parameter is not identified, but I am not sure if it is valid statistically since the size of the coefficient vector varies across samples.

```
/* (1) Custom Bootstrap Program Version */
capture program drop my_clust_mvreg_bs
program define my_clust_mvreg_bs, rclass
    mvreg ln_wage wks_work hours = c.tenure i.ind_code

    local b1 = _b[ln_wage:tenure]
    local b2 = _b[wks_work:tenure]
    local b3 = _b[hours:tenure]

    ereturn clear

    return scalar b1 = `b1'
    return scalar b2 = `b2'
    return scalar b3 = `b3'
end

bootstrap b1=r(b1) b2=r(b2) b3=r(b3), reps(1000) seed(1) cluster(idcode) idcluster(newid) group(idcode) saving("bs1.dta", replace): my_clust_mvreg_bs 
test b1 b2 b3
```

Comment: Dimitriy, you are a genius. I was not aware of the suest option. Initially it did not work for me because of a "Warning:
> variance matrix is nonsymmetric or highly singular" error, which led to an empty estimates table for every equation. I fixed this by grouping all "sparse" categorical groups with $<10$ obsertations into a new "other" group that has more observations. Now suest works like a charm! It is even better than my bootstrap because it is faster and independent of seed. Thank you!

Comment: One comment on your bootstrap solution: I ran your code but added the "noisily" option . In many bootstrap samples the same problem as in my case occurs (see the collinearity error in the question). Indeed, your bootstrap output shows several red x, which indicates that this problem occured in that bootstrap sample. My understanding is that the estimates reported by mvreg after bootstrapping only use the bootstrap samples without that error, i.e., only those with "dots" and not with red crosses. Thus, effectively the bootstrap results are based on fewer than the requested replications.

Comment: So, alas, the bootstrap solution does not actually seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nameless Glad this helped. I can't speak to what's happening in your data. My thought for this example was that since both approaches have similar test statistics and p-values, maybe Stata is doing the right thing after all. The coefficients' SEs and CIs are based on the non-problematic samples, so they are of appropriate size in some sense. This example is also pretty pathological, where ~40% of the BS samples are problematic, and in a normal dataset this would be less of a problem. I also wonder if you just increase the reps by ~60% ( or use the reject() option) if that would be right.

Comment: Hi Dimitriy! I am not quite sure if the bootstrapped statistics are "right", given that the remaining samples are selected in a specific way and therefore not random. This would not be helped by just increasing the number of replications. I think a bootstrap solution would have to achieve that all of the samples are used to calculate the statistics (either by fixing the errors or by ignoring them - since the errors occur in some nuisance variables and not in the estimates of the variable of interest.) In any case, fortunately the suest method works!